# Unsatisfied dependency error in Spring project

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple Spring project which includes Product, ProductRepository and ProductdataApplication classes. It will connect to MySQL database and save product into this database via JUnit test. 
Unfortunately, when I try to run a test, an error appears.

I tried to add @ComponentScan with path to the ProductRepository, @EnableJpaRepository, checked hierarchy of the project, but none of this solved the problem. Spring does not see ProductRepository class. 
In one question here I saw the answer that I should add annotations only to classes, not to interfaces. Yeah, when I create ProjectRepositoryImpl that implements ProjectRepository, then inject it in JUnit test, no errors appears. However, it adds nothing to the database because of need to override all standard methods of CrudRepository. It doesn't make any sense.

I really hope for your help.

Part of error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bharath.springdata.product.ProductdataApplicationTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository';
```

All stack trace:

```
2019-04-11 10:00:25.548 ERROR 22997 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@289d1c02] to prepare test instance [com.bharath.springdata.product.ProductdataApplicationTest@22ffa91a]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bharath.springdata.product.ProductdataApplicationTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.bharath.springdata.product.com.bharath.springdata.product.repos.ProductRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) ~[spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) [junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.bharath.springdata.product.com.bharath.springdata.product.repos.ProductRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

ProductdataApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration

    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude =     {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,     HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ProductdataApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductdataApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Product.java:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Product {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String desc;
    private Double price;

//Gettters and setters
}
```

ProductRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer> {
}
```

ProductdataApplicationTest.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ProductdataApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(1);
        product.setName("Iphone");
        product.setDesc("Awesome");
        product.setPrice(1000d);

        repository.save(product);
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bharath.springdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>productdata</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>productdata</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to everyone !!!

Problem was due to the exclude configuration DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class. It was inserted unconsciously. 
The main problem was in trying to connect to the database, and I "got rid" this errors with this annotation. Haha :)

Comment: Exception seems to be thrown when trying to run the tests. Are you getting the same results when running the application as well?

Comment: You've excluded the configurations (`DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class`,     `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class`) which look for repository beans. Why?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex, application immediately shutdown without reference to the repository.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko, that's really good question. Honestly, i added that annotation without any though, just because of error "Failed to load ApplicationContext" with "Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]". But now I delete it and see that it makes a lot of sense. Perhaps this annotation was the main cause of the problems. Now I am trying to deal with these errors.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko, thank you very much!!! I figured it out and it worked! Next time I will be more meaningful to insert unfamiliar annotations

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the magic word: @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "package.where.your.repositories.are")

add it to your configuration class

:)

Comment: Unfortunately, I get "Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!".

Comment: The problem was different. Now the application works regardless of the presence of this annotation. It surprises me. I thought, in my case, this annotation is required.

Comment: sorry, how have you fixed the problem?

Comment: I deleted the annotation `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude =     {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})`, got "Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password", then changed version of MySQL Connector to 5.1.46.

Answer (score 0):

I have been through this couple of times. My two cents.

Cent #1

Try enabling component scan.

In your ProductdataApplication add component scan like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan (basePackages = "your.base.package.name.here")
```

Cent # 2

Also make sure if you have any Service(s) they are annotated with @Service. Try this and share your outcome.

(Key is to - scan all your repositories, configurations, services, components at load/compile time, without fail)

Comment: Problem was due to the exclude configuration DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class. I tried to run the application with and without @ComponentScan, and it now works regardless of the presence of annotations. Thank you anyway!